# How to compare first item in sublist of numbers, if repeated, compare the second item and pick the sublist with the smallest second item?

Tags: python, list, numbers, minimum, sublist

I have a list of lists with numbers (LIST_long) and I need to write a list (LIST_short) which contains for each first item (a sequence number of an amino acid) only one sublist with the smallest second item (distance):

```
LIST_long = [['1', '50.9'], ['1', '9.0'], ['1', '10.2'], ['1', '2.0'], ['2', '50.1'], ['2', '8.8'],...]

LIST_short = [['1', '2.0'], ['2', '8.8'],...]
```

I wrote such code in Python 3.6:

```
import itertools

LIST_long = [['1', '50.9'], ['1', '9.0'], ['1', '10.2'], ['1', '2.0'], ['2', '50.1'], ['2', '8.8'],...]
LIST_short = []
LIST_long = sorted(LIST_long, key=lambda x:(x[0], x[1]))

for x, y in itertools.groupby(LIST_long, lambda x: x[0]):
    LIST_short.append(list(y)[0])
print(LIST_short)
```

output:

```
LIST_short = [['1', '10.2'], ['2', '50.1'],...]
```

instead of :

```
LIST_short = [['1', '2.0'], ['2', '8.8'], ...]
```

But in this way `['1', '10.2']` is appended instead of `['1', '2.0']` since as I understood not the number of the second item but the digit by digit are compared and 1 comes before 2; 5 before 8 and so on....

I would be very grateful for the help with this problem.
Looking forward for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly, you just need to change `x[1]` into `float(x[1])` :

```
import itertools

LIST_long = [['1', '50.9'], ['1', '9.0'], ['1', '10.2'], ['1', '2.0'], ['2', '50.1'], ['2', '8.8'],...]
LIST_short = []
LIST_long = sorted(LIST_long, key=lambda x:(x[0], float(x[1])))    # <<-- here

for x, y in itertools.groupby(LIST_long, lambda x: x[0]):
    LIST_short.append(list(y)[0])
print(LIST_short)
```

The result:

```
>>> LIST_short
[['1', '2.0'], ['2', '8.8']]
>>>
```

Problem was, you were comparing the second elements as strings, when you should have converted them into `float` values for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

you can use dictionary to get the result, store the first item of sublist as key for the dictionary, and corresponding to that add the second item as the value in the list, then get the minimum of the list and you got the required result.

```
LIST_long = [['1', '50.9'], ['1', '9.0'], ['1', '10.2'], ['1', '2.0'], ['2', '50.1'], ['2', '8.8']]

from collections import defaultdict as dd

x = dd(list)

for i in LIST_long:
    x[i[0]]+=[float(i[1])]

LIST_sort = []

for k, v in x.items():
    LIST_sort.append([k, str(min(v))])

print(LIST_sort)
```

output

```
[['1', '2.0'], ['2', '8.8']]
```

Comment: Thank you @sahasrara62 yours is also very nice solution of the problem

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it:

```
LIST_long = [['1', '50.9'], ['1', '9.0'], ['1', '10.2'], ['1', '2.0'], ['2', '50.1'], ['2', '8.8']]
LIST_short = dict()

for id, value in LIST_long:
    if id not in LIST_short or float(value) < float(LIST_short[id]):
        LIST_short[id] = value

LIST_short = [[x, y] for x, y in LIST_short.items()]
```

Comment: Your code outputs: `LIST_short  ->> [['1', '10.2'], ['2', '50.1']]`, which is wrong.